# Can I make vim replicate file changes over ssh?

Tags: vim, vi

What I am trying to ask here is, say I have a repo cloned in a virtual machine and in my local machine. When I open a file from the repo in my local machine, edit it and save it, can I replicate that file state in the repo in my virtual machine as well? Basically, when I press `:w` I want to see the changes in my other repo without having to push my local changes to remote and then pull them in my virtual machine. I know some IDE's can do this but was not able to find if its possible via vim.

Comment: someting like `vim scp://remoteuser@server.tld//path/to/document` ?

Comment: how about sync by dropbox? ;)

Comment: Does it have to be triggered by Vim?  Inotify can be configured to provide the functionality but it watches the file system for changes rather than being triggered by Vim.  I use it to replicate a Tiddlywiki instance across machines.

Answer (score 1):

My [DuplicateWrite plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4722) hooks into `:write` to save the file to another location(s), too. If you mount your remote location or use the built-in *netrw* plugin via `scp://hostname/path/to/file`, you can therefore achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I think the feature you are looking for is "collaborative editing" and the only plugin I know of is [CoVim](https://github.com/FredKSchott/CoVim). But I have not tested it, so can't vouch for it.